# Druid with transactional Kafka producer : delays after running some days

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, druid

We have a system which write data to druid via a kafka producer which uses transactions through a Flink job. This job runs with 30 second checkpointing.

also, we have some messages going to druid via a kafka rest via the same kafka topic. But we just send them to kafka rest. We don't manage any transactions. After running few days we, monitored some delays of like 30 seconds for events coming from kafka rest to druid.

We use confluent 4.1.1 for kafka and kafka rest. And druid 0.17.

These are the druid consumer configs.

```
"consumerProperties": {
      "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
      "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
      "isolation.level": "read_committed"
 }
```

This is how we made the kafka producer in flink.

```
configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, 60*10 * 1000);
FlinkKafkaProducer011 producer011 = new FlinkKafkaProducer011<>(
      "KAFKA_TOPIC",
      new KeyedSerializationSchemaWrapper<>(new AnalyticsEventSchema()),
      configProperties,
      Optional.of(new AnalyticsCustomPartitioner()),
      FlinkKafkaProducer011.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE,
      FlinkKafkaProducer011.DEFAULT_KAFKA_PRODUCERS_POOL_SIZE + 5);


producer011.setWriteTimestampToKafka(true);
```

Comment: So you want to know what is causing the delay, right?

Comment: Yes, can not understand how delay happens, is due to a default config, or due to transactions or else